# "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal" in ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am unable to get the response from ajax. please guide me how to resolve this error,

XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{eba9a0c1-19c1-45a3-9bb3-457899f1aaac} Line Number 1, Column 1:

```
 $(".sub_cat4").change(function()
                {
                    var s_class =  $(this).attr('class');
                    $num = 5;
                    var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
         jQuery.ajax
            ({
                url: '/products/get_attribute/' + option+ '/'+$num,
                success: function(data)
                  {
                    if(data != '' )
                     {
                     // $('#attribute').append(data);
                     jQuery( "#attribute").show();
                     jQuery( "#attribute").html( data );
                    }
                }
            });     
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is from your JAVA server, post the server code for the AJAX call. Is the server in the same place as the js file?